# Why extension function is not visible in another module?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

My Android project has two modules:

```
app
common
```

In *settings.gradle*:

```
rootProject.name='My project'
include ':app'
include ':common'
```

In my build.gradle:

```
implementation project(':common')
```

In common package I has *StringUtil.kt* with the next extension function:

```
fun String.isEmailValid(): Boolean {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(this) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(this).matches()
}
```

And in **this** class I can use extension function like this:

```
val str = ""
str.isEmailValid()
```

But in `app` module I has class

```
class RegistrationViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

  fun doClickRegistration(email: String?, password: String?, retypePassword: String?) {
        val str = ""
        str.isEmailValid()
    }
}
```

But now I get compile error:

> Unresolved reference: isEmailValid

Comment: You ever find out why this was the case, Alexei? I see the official answer explains that what you saw should not happen, and I have just had this exact problem on my side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If you do not specify any visibility modifier, public is used by default, which means that your declarations will be visible everywhere; ([Source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#visibility-modifiers))

Since you didn't add any visibility modifier to `isEmailValid` it is regarded as `public`.

Please note that extension functions have to be imported.

```
import com.your.package.path.isEmailValid
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app `build.gradle` add this:

```
implementation project(':common')
```